# How do i remove the blue circle with an "A" in it next to a caller I did not block?

Tags: samsung

How do I remove the blue circle with an "A" in it next to a caller I did not block? It's next to my elderly mother's # & she needs to be able to call! I actually have two numbers that have that blue circle with the "A", and they are both very important numbers.

**I would really like to know how to unblock a number on the phone.**

Answer (score 0):

The icon (circle with a letter) next to the contact name is a default icon.  If you had a photo attached, it would display here.  It does not mean that the contact is blocked.

If it shows an A, then it's likely that the contact's name begins with an **A**.

### Blocking

Contacts as such are not blocked.  The blocking is in phone and message apps.

1. Open Phone app
2. Press on hamburger menu
3. Select Settings
4. Select **Block Numbers**

OR

1. Open Message (SMS) app
2. Press three dot menu
3. Select Settings
4. Select **Block Numbers and messages**

Blocked numbers will be shown here.  And you can unblock them here too.

Comment: My mother has been blocked from calling.  I looked up what the blue circle with an "A" in it was, and it said that a contact was blocked.  My question is, how do i remove it.  Her number or the other contact is not is not in my blocked list, so I don't know what is going on.  It seems like some kind of fluke.

Comment: The icon has nothing to do with contact being blocked.  Your question was how to remove the icon, which is not an issue.